# Facebook Marketing API - Add Users to Custom Audience

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I'm trying to add users to a custom audience via API.

My schema looks like this:

```
"schema": [
  EMAIL,
  PHONE,
  LN,
  FN,
  ZIP
]
```

My data looks like this:

```
"data": [
  [
    hashWithKey("john.smith@xxx.com", "EMAIL"),
    "12345678910", // -> No hashing, since there's no HASH key specified in docs.
    hashWithKey("John", "LN"),
    hashWithKey("Smith", "FN")
    hashWithKey("1919", "ZIP")
  ],
  ...
]
```

Although I'm getting an OK response from the API, I'm not sure how to check if the audience was created as I wanted.

1. Is it OK not to hash the phone number? If not, what key should I be
   using? I tried with `PHONE` and I still got an OK from the API. So
   I'm confused.
2. When using CSV files to create the audience, I can specify the field
   `age`. According to Facebook docs, seems not to be possible to
   specify `age` via API. Is it enough by sending `DOBY`? Does anyone figured this out?

These are the best links I could find:

- "*Hashing and Normalization for Multi-Key*" at:
  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/audiences-api
- `Payload Parameters` at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/custom-audience/users

Comment: See "Multi-key Matching" in the link you provided: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/audiences-api  `$schema = array(  CustomAudienceMultikeySchemaFields::FIRST_NAME,
  CustomAudienceMultikeySchemaFields::LAST_NAME,
  CustomAudienceMultikeySchemaFields::EMAIL,);
$customAudienceMultiKey->addUsers($users, $schema);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what I did to make it work:

- I didn't hash the data
- I set `is_raw: true`
- I cleaned up my data: Some of the emails were comming with quotes, like "john.smith@xxx.com"

Being that done, everything worked as expected.